# loop variable (i) being mysteriously reset to 0 after each loop while debugging in Visual Studio (works when not debugging)

Tags: c#

I am trying to read some memory from a process in C#. Here is my helper function to obtain a pointer address from a series of offsets, along with relevant other functions:

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern Int32 ReadProcessMemory(
        IntPtr hProcess,
        IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
        [In, Out] byte[] buffer,
        UInt32 size,
        out int lpNumberOfBytesRead);

    public static bool ReadProcessMemoryHelper(
        IntPtr hProcess,
        long lpBaseAddress,
        [In, Out] byte[] buffer,
        UInt32 size,
        out int lpNumberOfBytesRead)
    {
        return ReadProcessMemory(
            hProcess,
            new IntPtr(lpBaseAddress),
            buffer,
            size,
            out lpNumberOfBytesRead) != 0;
    }
    public long Pointer(params int[] Offsets)
    {
        long pointerAddress = _baseAddr;

        if (Offsets.Length > 1)
        {
            byte[] buff = new byte[4];
            for (int i = 0; i < Offsets.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                int bytesRead;
                var cur = pointerAddress;
                var offset = Offsets[i];
                var next = cur + offset;
                Console.WriteLine("i = {0}", i);
                Console.WriteLine("[{0}+{1}], {2}", cur.ToString("X"), offset.ToString("X"), next.ToString("X"));

                if (0 == cur)
                {
                    return 0;
                }

                var readProcess = ReadProcessMemoryHelper(
                    _process.Handle,
                    next,
                    buff,
                    4,
                    out bytesRead);
                if (readProcess)
                {
                    pointerAddress = BitConverter.ToUInt32(buff, 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("i = {0}", i);
            }
        }

        return pointerAddress + Offsets[Offsets.Length - 1];
    }
```

Mysteriously, after ReadProcessMemoryHelper is called, the loop variable i becomes 0. This loop only terminates because eventually it fails to read memory from the process, returning 0.

Here is some example output:

```
i = 0
[170000+FB02F0], 11202F0
i = 0
i = 1
[11469240+1C], 1146925C
i = 0
i = 1
[12DCC690+1C], 12DCC6AC
i = 0
i = 1
[114673A0+1C], 114673BC
i = 0
i = 1
[10F2C830+1C], 10F2C84C
i = 0
i = 1
[111561E0+1C], 111561FC
i = 0
i = 1
[E972CAE+1C], E972CCA
i = 0
i = 1
[1302736E+1C], 1302738A
i = 0
i = 1
[3E49+1C], 3E65
```

Perhaps even more mysteriously. This ONLY happens when the debugger is attached (Talk about a Heisenbug). If I run this from the command line, I get the following (correct) output:

```
i = 0
[170000+FB02F0], 11202F0
i = 0
i = 1
[11469240+1C], 1146925C
i = 1
i = 2
[12DCC690+10], 12DCC6A0
i = 2
i = 3
[113E4430+130], 113E4560
i = 3
i = 4
[10F2CEF0+1C], 10F2CF0C
i = 4
```

I have no idea what could possibly be doing this, and it's driving me nuts.

Comment: Well, the debugger is messing with threading in order to set breakpoints. Have you attempted to use old-fashioned Console output to trace instead?

Comment: There are no breakpoints. The output provided is from, as you put it, old-fashioned Console output. The only difference between these is that one is started via F5, and the other via ctrl-F5 from Visual Studio (debugger attached vs. no debugger attached).

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser. If I add this line:

    var tmpBSVariable = 0xDEADBEEF;

In the first line of the for loop, that variable is set to 0 after the call, and i increments normally / the code works as expected. My only theory is that the Visual Studio debugger is just busted in VS2013 when interfacing with kernel.dll / possibly other native components, and messes with the stack in managed code.

Comment: Is the process 64-bit?

Comment: "My only theory is that the Visual Studio debugger is busted..." Another theory you need to add to your repertoire is "My code has a bug."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess that your process in 64-bit. If that is the case then the interop signature is incorrect as the size of the last parameter, `lpNumberOfBytesRead` should be 64-bits rather than 32-bits.

```
BOOL WINAPI ReadProcessMemory(
    _In_  HANDLE  hProcess,
    _In_  LPCVOID lpBaseAddress,
    _Out_ LPVOID  lpBuffer,
    _In_  SIZE_T  nSize,
    _Out_ SIZE_T  *lpNumberOfBytesRead);



#if defined(_WIN64)
typedef unsigned __int64 ULONG_PTR;
#else
typedef unsigned long ULONG_PTR;
#endif

typedef ULONG_PTR SIZE_T;
```

You can imagine how this would cause stack corruption. Since you ignore the out parameter anyways you could use an IntPtr in the signature.

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer you earlier -- the process is 64 bit (or more specifically, it's compiled as Any CPU running on a 64 bit machine). Changing the int to a IntPtr seems to have done the trick. Thanks for pointing that out! I'm still surprised it manifests as stack corruption in the managed code, but you're right that it's not difficult to imagine that it could have done this.